# Difference between step up and down converter

Tags: pcb, dc, boost, converter

I have bought 2 different PCB DC to DC converters, I would like to use these for converting 5V from a battery pack to 12V.

Only issue is that being the fool I am, I have ordered "step down" converters and not "step up" converters. 
Therefor I just wan't to make sure, before ordering anything else. That if the input into the "step down" converter is 5V, there is NO WAY to increase that voltage? 
To increase the voltage it has to be a "step up" converter?

When turning the two screws for voltage and current, nothing happens it just stays at 5.08V

I know it is a rather noob question, but while buying I was distracted by the fact that the converters, just stated that they could take 5V-32V to 0.8V-30V

Comment: Next time buy step up/down converted (buck/boost). No there is no way to step up with a step-down converter.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I appreciate your response, so I guess I just have to purchase some new converters. Of which actually says "step up" converter and it will be fine? Like this https://goo.gl/bWKCi3

Comment: Can you show what do you have?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I currently have this https://goo.gl/9Bwg22 and this https://goo.gl/HgQbRq

Comment: Yep. These are built around a buck converter.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So my best bet is to just purchase the one I linked to first? That seems to be a "boost/step up" converter, as long as what is advertised is right.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask here the real question, describing what your problem is :) Maybe these are not a solution for it at all.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have a battery bank using regular Lithium Ion 18650 batteries, it uses a USB so the output is 5V 2A. I want to input this battery pack into a boost converter and then turn those 5V into 12V or more.

Comment: Step down (buck) means \$V_{Out} < V_{In}\$.  Step up (boost) means \$V_{Out} > V_{In}\$.  It has to do with how the inductor is connected.  So these will never step up 5V to 12V.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I appreciate your message, I have done quite a stupid mistake I see.

Comment: Only costly in time.